# Rails 3 Routes - allowing for slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

What is the correct way to set up the routes to allow an extra path element (a slug) to be passed to a URL in Rails 3. I'd like to not break some of the magic you get with show and new when you list a object as a resource.

Here is an example:
  http://somewebserver.com/topics/1/learning-rails
but I would still like this to work
  http://somewebserver.com/topics/1
and these
  http://somewebserver.com/topics/new
  http://somewebserver.com/topics/1/edit

Comment: URL stub is more commonly called a URL slug in rails community.  Not trying to be pedantic, just figure it may help people answering to understand you question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

While it's probably better to make your slugs look like "1-learning-rails", since Rails 3 now [allows the use of Rack applications](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/26/the-rails-3-router-rack-it-up/) to handle routes, so you could do something like this:

```
# lib/topic_slugger.rb
class TopicSlugger
  AD_KEY = "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"

  def self.call(env)
    controller = (env["PATH_INFO"].split("/")[1].camelize+"Controller").constantize
    glob = env[AD_KEY][:glob]
    slug, action_name = nil
    if glob
      path_params = glob.split("/")
      if path_params.length == 1
        if ["new","edit"].include?(path_params.first)
          # no slug present
          action_name = path_params.first
        else
          slug = path_params.first
        end
      else
        action_name = path_params.first
        slug = path_params.last
      end
    end
    env[AD_KEY][:slug] = slug if slug
    action = if action_name # "new" or "edit"
               action_name.to_sym
             else
               case env["REQUEST_METHOD"]
               when "PUT" then :update
               when "DELETE" then :destroy
               else :show
               end
             end
    controller.action(action).call(env)
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
require 'topic_slugger'

Ztest::Application.routes.draw do
  # handle show, new, edit, update, destroy
  match 'topics/:id/*glob' => TopicSlugger
  # handle index, create
  resources :topics
end
```

This takes requests of the form `"/topics/1/foo/bar"` and passes them to the TopicSlugger Rack app, which decides whether the glob contains a combination action/slug (like `"new/learning-rails"`), or just a slug (`"learning-rails"`), adds the slug to the environment's request parameters, then passes the environment to the controller action, which itself is a Rack application. "index" and "create" are handled normally by the `resources` statement.

So for example `"GET /topics/1/new/learning-rails"` would be dispatched to `TopicsController#new` with a params hash of `{ :id => "1", :slug => "learning-rails, :glob => "new/learning-rails" }`

Answer (score 0):

Because the `/` is considered a path separator, Rails encourage you to separate the ID from the `slug` using a `-` which is more "neutral".

See [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url).

Otherwise, you need to pass a custom `:id` validation and let Rails know that `:id` can include `/`, but it's not that simple.